# how to exit and log the data in file at same time in makefile when error occurs

Tags: c, bash, unix, makefile

makefile

```
RUN_EXE = xyz.exe
SOME_DIR_PATH = ../folder1/

ifdef $(MAKECMDGOALS)
   ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), "target_1")
      ABC = status.log
      ARGS_TO_EXE = "argc1"
   endif
   ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), "target_1")
      ABC = file2.txt
      ARGS_TO_EXE = "argc2"
   endif
else
   ABC = status.log file2.txt
   ARGS_TO_EXE = ""
endif

 # phony define
.PHONY = default target_1 target_2 

# if target not mention run default
default: $(ABC)


target_1 target_2:$(ABC)

$(ABC):
      $(CD) $(SOME_DIR_PATH) && ( $(RUN_EXE) $(ARGS_TO_EXE) || (exit 1;)) 2>&1 | tee -a ../status.log; \
```

i have two makefile using the first makefile i am invoking this makefile.
if some error come it should succesfully return to first makefile.

for testing purpose i created a error in executable i am trying to open a file in read mode which doesn't exist. so my executable will through error and it will come out

when i give

```
make target_1
```

error: error opening file (using c printf function and same will be in file)

```
make target_2
```

error: error opening file (using c printf function and same will be in file)

BUT problem occur here

```
make
```

error: error opening file (using c printf function and same will be in file).
error: error opening file (using c printf function and same will be in file).

it should exit after first print with successfully logging in status.log file but it is not happening. AS $(ABC) contain two target status.log and file2.txt so in first run it try to build status.log and in second it try to build file2.txt.

But i want if error is there in first run it should return to first makefile and log the error in status.log also and shouldn't run for file2.txt and come out using exit 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if some error come it should succesfully return to first makefile.

Your first makefile can invoke this makefile with `-` option, e.g.

```
run_submake:
    -$(MAKE) <arguments>
```

This way the error from the submake is ignored.

---

Your rules do not seem to be correct. The recipes must produce a file (or multiple files) or be phony targets. E.g., there should be rules to produce `status.log` and `file2.txt`. Your makefile should look like this:

```
RUN_EXE := xyz.exe
SOME_DIR_PATH := ../folder1/
ARGS_TO_EXE := "argc1"

all : status.log file2.txt # The default target.
target_1: status.log
target_2: file2.txt

.PHONY: all target_1 target_2

status.log:
    ${CD} ${SOME_DIR_PATH} && ( $(RUN_EXE) $(ARGS_TO_EXE) | tee -a $@; exit $${PIPESTATUS[0]} )

file2.txt:
    # Add a recipe to produce file2.txt
```

Comment: recipe is not changing for me only arguments to executable is changing. thats why i want to stick with single recipe .
I tried your recipe but it will not redirect the error generated to file.

Comment: @RohanG Use `|&`  redirection into `tee` instead of `|` to redirect both stdout and stderr into it.